# Text Box - How to not show already filled value

Tags: javascript, html

When a User click on a Text Box, 
How to not show already filled value which appears below the Text Box

Comment: I think this is a browser configuration thing and not something you can control with JavaScript.

Comment: Ehm what?

He prolly used Google translate or so...

Comment: Are you talking about values which are stored on the users browser or values which are defined for the `textarea` or `input` box (which one are you talking about btw?) by the website?

Answer (score 5):

Place this property in you textbox `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: This is the cleanest solution, but may be less robust than other hacks.